# How to display contents from MySql Database,chosen from a ComboBox, to a groupBox/TableWidget usning PyQt

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt, database-connection

I have a comboBox from which I select the Primary key data of my MySQL Database. I need to connect the combo box to my database, retrieve the whole row of that particular comboBox selection and display that in a groupBox.

I am not really sure how to go about with this, is there any link where I coudl get help from. I got the basic Database connection, where the Query

```
query = QSqlQuery ("SELECT * FROM entityinfo where structure_id='ID'")
```

displays the row for the particular ID.
**How do I connect the Combo-Box with this? I need my Query to function like**

```
query = QSqlQuery ("SELECT * FROM entityinfo where structure_id=***value selected from comboBox***")
```

Whatever selection I make in the Combobox, it should return the result for that selection, from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use query parameter substitution where you can create your query like:

```
query = QSqlQuery ("SELECT * FROM entityinfo where structure_id=?")
```

retrieve the selected value:

```
selected = myComboBox.selected()
```

and then you can execute it something like:

```
result = query.execute(selected)
```

pardon, I do not know the syntax for doing this in QT.  But, this should give you the idea of what to look for.